# Adding Contacts Cordova plugin in a IONIC Framework

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, ionic-framework

This is a IONIC project. I'm trying to add the cordova contacts plugin using the next command line but I get error

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.contacts
```

Result error:

```
Installing "org.apache.cordova.contacts" for android
Failed to install 'org.apache.cordova.contacts':Error: spawn EACCES
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:1162:11)
    at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:995:9)
    at Object.exports.spawn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:100:31)
    at Object.exports.maybeSpawn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:142:24)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:284:29
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:810:14
Error: spawn EACCES
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:1162:11)
    at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:995:9)
    at Object.exports.spawn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:100:31)
    at Object.exports.maybeSpawn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:142:24)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:284:29
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:810:14
```

Tried to add the sms plugin and the same problem.

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin.git
```

I'm able to add it in other projects...

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of ionic?

Comment: @QueryLars - Just updated again in case it wasn't using "ionic lib update" but I still have the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED!
This was a permission issue. Here is the solution:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 projectFolder
```

-R: recursive

Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesnt work for me: is projectFolder the main top-level folder or `hooks` or `platforms` or ?

Comment: @Eno Yes, the main top-level folder. Inside the projectFolder is located platforms,...